# basic css font-weight property not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

My html:

```
<div id="unsurpassed">
  <p>
    <span>FIRE </span>| Unsurpassed Efficacy
  </p>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#unsurpassed {
margin-top: 20px;
font-size: 32px;
font-family: "Myriad Pro";
}

#unsurpassed p {
color: #77787B; 
font-weight: 300;
}

#unsurpassed span {
color: #1D74B6; 
font-weight: 400; 
}
```

I want the phrase "| Unsurpassed Efficacy" to have a much lighter weight that "FIRE" currently that isn't happening, not really sure why.

Comment: Do you have Myriad Pro Light installed in your computer? Or are you using Myriad as a downloadable font, via `@font-face`? Exactly how?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `normal` and `bold` for `font-weight` instead of numbers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8rHbv/2/

CSS:

```
#unsurpassed {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro";
}
#unsurpassed p {
    color: #77787B;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#unsurpassed span {
    color: #1D74B6;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the font weights installed on your computer?

Try add important! after your css code here:

```
#unsurpassed {
margin-top: 20px;
font-size: 32px;
font-family: "Myriad Pro";
}

#unsurpassed p {
color: #77787B; 
font-weight: 300;
}

#unsurpassed p span {
color: #1D74B6; 
font-weight: 900 !important; 
}
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GeUj3/1/

Comment: That didn't change anything?

Comment: Edited my answer @user3762122. Note that I don't have the Myriad font so I used Georgia instead.

Comment: using `!important` is not good advice, and it did not accomplish anything here.. The difference is because you changed the value from `400` to `900`, not because of the `!important`

Comment: There is no difference in Georgia 400 and 300. It was merely an example. If my solution does not work then there is probably something wrong with the font itself. Maybe he does not have the specific font weight he needs.

Comment: He does have a specif weight, or I wouldn't be killing myself over this. nothing is working

Comment: If you open the two different font weights side by side can you tell the difference in (for example) a font viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Use **`bolder`** or **`bold`** value along with **`300`** or **`400`** value and check this work perfect...

```
#unsurpassed {
margin-top: 20px;
font-size: 32px;
font-family: "Myriad Pro";
}

#unsurpassed p {
color: #77787B; 
font-weight: bolder !important;
}

#unsurpassed span {
color: #1D74B6; 
font-weight: 400; 
}
```

Also use **`important`** word.

#### Check this <kbd>**[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RB5rx/)**</kbd>

Comment: it isn't responding to anything below bold, and I need it too.

Answer (score 0):

You are visually not going to notice a difference between font-weight 300 and 400
You can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8rHbv/)

```
#unsurpassed {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
}

#unsurpassed p span {
    color: #1D74B6;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#unsurpassed p {
    color: #77787B; 
}
```

You can check the different font weights [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_font-weight&preval=900)

Comment: it only responds to bold, but I need it to respond to other values on the continuum

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is valid CSS and should work if the system contains both regular and light typeface of Myriad Pro. Most computers do not contain either of them; this is a different topic, but may affect the analysis of this problem, since you might be looking at the rendering in some other font (the browser’s fallback font) if Myriad Pro is not available.

I cannot test the exact code since my system lacks Myriad Pro, but testing with DejaVu Sans instead, with no other change to the code, on Win 7, I noticed that IE 11 shows “| Unsurpassed Efficacy” in DejaVu Sans Light but Chrome and Firefox use DejaVu Sans (regular) instead, even though developer tools show that the CSS rules are being applied. You may have encountered a similar browser problem.

In general, typefaces lighter than normal (400) often work poorly even in modern browsers. A workaround is to use a light typeface as if it were a font family, with normal `font-weight`. This works on the browsers tested for DejaVu Sans.

So the following may work in your situation: in the rule for `#unsurpassed p`, replace `font-weight: 300` by `font-family: "Myriad Pro Light"`.

Answer (score -1):

Its because your not putting the class IDs in your html, if you don't then the CSS does not know what to do.. and you cant conflict the class id elements.

```
<div class="unsurpassed">
<p>
<span class="unsurpassed span">FIRE </span><span class="unsurpassed p">| Unsurpassed Efficacy<span>
</p>
</div>
```

Remember that css class elements are global, so label were you want the css to work in the proper place and don't have then conflict.

Comment: `#unsupparsed` is an **id selector**, and it is used as a **descendant combination** in most instances.